# Updating DB and Migration Asp.net.core

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

CodeFirst Approach.
I have a multi project solution.
My Projects are structured by. AccessService, ModelService and the ProjectName for the razorpages and rest of the code.
TestDb: I have an existing database and Migration called TestDb. I want to update my Migration then Update the database for any edit or new models which the db needs to save.

The a migration has multple models in the table, Student is one of them. The Table Student has: Student Id student name, I want to add StudentGrade to the Student table. So the table Student has a new field Grade. Another example would be. I want to add  the Model Class Room. It does not exist in the original migration or db. I want to add it to the DB so it holds a new table ClassRoom.

I have FramewWorkCore.tools(6.0.13), same version for sqlServer.
When i use these commands i just get errors.
I've tried Force, IgnoreChanges and f.
I solved one large problem.
Now i got another.

```
Your target project 'ProjectPortal' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'ProjectAccessService'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ProjectPortal")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.
```

So my understanding is, i need to somehow tell entityframework to change the target to AccessService

Comment: It might be worth trying the [EF Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) as well, see if it produces the same errors. That EF Core CLI command might look like `dotnet ef migrations add TestDb --force`.

Comment: hmm i believe, it will be `dotnet ef migration <projectname> add-migration TestDb --Force`

Comment: Could not execute because the speficied command or file was not found.

Comment: You need to have the EF Core CLI installed (`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`) for that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. This is meant for multiple projekts.
If you have an AccessService and a AllProjekt like i do,
You need to add this.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>

options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnectionString"),
    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ProjektAccessService")));
```

ProjektAccessService is the name of your Solution/projekt.
You do not start a Migration before adding this. If your migratet your before adding this, i can't help you.

I added this, then i started my first Migration. Updated the database.
Tried my 2nd Migration, updated the database. It works. Is it a solution for all. deferentially not. Is it dumb, 100%.

Comment: PS. don't use ensuredatabase created. It does not work correctly with update-database. 
Use one of them. I would suggest using update-database.